# How do I retrieve an ajax friendly phtml file?

Tags: module, template, theme

I have created a custom front end module that allows a user to go through a wizard like process. I would like to make this AJAX.

I am loading my layout block with the following

```
<batch_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="batch/batch" name="batch" template="batch/batch.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</batch_index_index>
```

However the default template is being returned with that phtml file, how do I get magento to return just the contents of the phtml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<batch_index_index>
    <block type="batch/batch" name="root" template="batch/batch.phtml"/>
</batch_index_index>
```

Comment: You should probably wrap the rendered phtml inside of a json response. That will make error handling and your js in general a lot nicer.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is, that you generate the block in the controller:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($name);
$this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($block->toHtml()));
```

*edit* added json_encode as suggested from @sparcksoft

Answer (score 0):

Here's one module on [Github](https://github.com/subeshpokhrel/ajaxify) which helps developer to work on Magento, with Ajax. It is also available on [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajaxify-8411.html).